# How can i make string save into a text file only if it starts with !test?

Tags: java

```
    try {
        Scanner Majora = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what is your name?");
        String Link = Majora.nextLine();
        Scanner Lenk = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("name of file?");
        String Lunk = Lenk.nextLine();
        if(Link.equalsIgnoreCase("!addcom");
        File ocarina = new File("/Users/Unknown/Desktop/commands/" + Lunk + ".txt");
        if (ocarina.exists()) {
            ocarina.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter Majoras = new FileWriter(ocarina.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter Zelda = new BufferedWriter(Majoras);
        Zelda.write(Link);
        Zelda.close();
}
```

this is what i got so far :/

i need help on making it like if a certain word is used before the string you wanna save. save the string.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use startswith string method

```
if(Link.startsWith("!test"))
Zelda.write(Link);
```

substring will get you the string without !test which is 5 characters

```
Link = Link.substring(5);
```

Comment: but then wouldn't it also write !test into the text file? i would only want the string after !test to save into the text file.

Comment: edited the question how to get the string without !test on it